# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed after upgrade to 2.3.0

Tags: foreign-key

Please help!!!!!! I am upgrading from 2.1.7 to ver 2.3.0 I am stuck. I am not sure how no one else has the same issue. nothing related to this table on any forum. I am unable to Truncate, Delete this table due Foreign key constraint. I tried to delete the customer_group table i get this ("Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails") 
when I Truncate I get this message ("Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`aayebmfmry`.`catalog_product_bundle_price_index`, CONSTRAINT `catalog_product_bundle_price_index_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_group_id`) REFERENCES `aayebmfmry`.`customer_group` (`customer_"

luckily this is a staging environment, so I have done upgrade couple times and I cannot get past this nightmare table.

after removing some old modules and updating it to php 7.1 - the upgrades goes smoothly and the next step is (php bin/magento setup:upgrade)
This is the message i get....

Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed), query was: ALTER TABLE `customer_group` MODIFY COLUMN `customer_group_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT

This option doesnt really work...no table are effected when i run this query

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; 
TRUNCATE table customer_group; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: run it on mysql CLI

Comment: I am using CLI..a terminal service (SSH)

Comment: make sure the user has the right permission to modify your schema

Comment: as far as i know I am a super user -

Comment: do you have phpMyadmin or any database gui? If yes, maybe try to run it on its SQL query interface and check if you still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue upgrading from 2.1.9 to 2.3.1

The issue was given by `customer_group_id` that was used as foreign key on a table of a 3rd part module.

I solved removing the tables of that module that were unused and running again
`bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Hope it helps